# How to run tests parameterized by defines

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing

I have a test suite (more like a homegrown maze of tests we use at work) that, as mentioned in the title, is parameterized by macro definitions. To give a rough picture, the code looks like this:

1. Input creation

   ```
   void make_input(vector<data> &v)
   {
   #if INPT_RANDOM_GENERATION
       /* fill v accordingly */
   #elif INPT_READ_FROM_FILE
       /* fill v accordingly */
   #else
   #error Not a valid input generation method
   #endif
   }
   ```
2. Pre-processing

   ```
   void pre_process_input(vector<data> &v)
   {
   #if PP_SANITIZE
       /* mutate v accordingly */
   #elif PP_DO_NADA
       /* leave v alone */
   #else
   #error Not a valid input pre-processing method
   #endif
   }
   ```
3. Run algorithms

   ```
   void run_algorithms(vector<data> &v)
   {
   #if RUN_SERIAL
       /* ... */
   #elif RUN_PARALLEL
       /* ... */
   #else
   #error Not a valid algorithm
   #endif
   }
   ```
4. Post-processing

   ```
   // well you get the gist
   ```

So, running this thing is a bit cumbersome, not because of the `#define`s you'd have to toggle, but because something might be left out. For now, I'm actually tweaking the macro list and re-compiling to have different runs. Is there a better way?

### P.S.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition and no no-one will port this test suite to the VS test framework. I was thinking maybe a batch file trick would be a good idea but I don't know how to do this. Then again if a totally different alternative exists I'd like to know.

Comment: Any reason not to use an existing testing framework?

Comment: @ZivS It's legacy code, I'm not building the tests like this

Comment: Why was it designed like this in the first place? I mean what was the motive? Is changing the preprocessor defines with variables read from a configuration file an option?